# How can I clear Material UI DatePicker input?

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, material-ui

I would like to add a 'clear' button to a `DatePicker` from `@mui/lab` (5.0.0-alpha.55).

What I am attempting:

- Store a `date` field in state, passed as the `value` prop to `DatePicker`
- Change the `date` to `null` when desired to 'clear' the value & input

The behaviour I observe:

- If the `date` is valid, it works as expected, and the input is cleared
- If the `date` is not valid, the `error` is cleared, but the invalid date still stays in the input.

The rudimentary version I have attempted which shows the behaviour above can be seen [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/clearable-date-picker-forked-b0co7?file=/src/App.tsx).

If you input a partial date, then click `clear`, you can observe that the input does not get cleared.

I would prefer to avoid a solution that involves changing the `key`, as that brings other issues, such as not respecting an external source changing the `date` to `null`, and needing additional hacks to respect the `label` transition when clearing the input.

Comment: DatePicker now supports clear action: ==> https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/custom-components/#action-bar <==

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My theory is that internally, `DatePicker` only updates the input value if it's different with the last *valid* value. Below is how the bug can occur:

- You clear the `DatePicker` when there is a valid value (like the initial `Date`), the state is reset successfully at first (`value=null`, `inputValue=''`)
- You enter some invalid date. The state is now (`value=Invalid Date`, `inputValue='invalid Text'`)
- Because the current `value` is invalid, it does not count and the `DatePicker` references the last valid value instead which is `null`, then decide that the current value doesn't change and skip dispatching the new input value (`value=null`, `inputValue='invalid Text'`).

I'd classify this as a bug from MUI, you can create an [issue](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues) on github if you want it to be fixed. In the meanwhile, you can fix the bug by applying this [patch](https://github.com/MOHAMMADArsalan/material-ui/commit/72de2acc683c184960b295c914280a449f761952) using [`patch-package`](https://github.com/ds300/patch-package):

- Install `patch-package`: `npm i patch-package`
- Add `postinstall` script in the `package.json`

```
"scripts": {
  "postinstall": "patch-package"
}
```

- Open the buggy file at `node_modules\@mui\lab\internal\pickers\hooks\useMaskedInput.js` and change it based on [this](https://github.com/MOHAMMADArsalan/material-ui/commit/72de2acc683c184960b295c914280a449f761952) commit.
- Run `npx patch-package @mui/lab` to create the patch that will be applied every time after you ran `npm i @mui/lab` again.
- Restart your dev server.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Unfortunately that solution doesn't work properly. It causes an issue with the follow-up onChange event where the cursor stays at the start of the input after inputting the first character. I'll file a github issue as it seems like this needs to be fixed internally to fully behave properly.

Edit: I found an existing github issue describing the problem here: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/29001

Comment: @JoshFraser see my updated answer. The code from the issue you linked above should fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks @NearHuscarl. Your updated answer worked well, but I had to also change the file at `node_modules\@mui\lab\node\internal\pickers\hooks\useMaskedInput.js` in addition to the location you provided, in order for my `jest` tests to get the changes too.

Answer (score 18):

For `@mui/x-date-pickers` v5 you could do:

```
<DatePicker
  componentsProps={{
    actionBar: {
      actions: ['clear'],
    },
  }}
  onAccept={(newDate) => {
    console.log(newDate);
  }}
/>
```

and see if `newDate` is `null`.

Important updates:

1. For `@mui/x-date-pickers` v6 please see the other comment
2. By default mobile and desktop don't have the same behavior, and just specifying `clear` will make the user stuck on mobile. Consider having `['clear', 'accept']` for mobile and `['clear']` for desktop, or simpler, merge the behavior by using the property `closeOnSelect={true|false}` to force on both platforms.

Comment: `componentsProps` is deprecated, can now use `slotProps` instead

Answer (score 8):

As an extension to [Thomas' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75213269/8498400), you can pass `clear` to the `slotProps` if you are using MUI 5:

```
<MobileDatePicker
  ...
  slotProps={{
    actionBar: {
      actions: ['clear']
    }
  }}
  ...
/>
```

References:

- https://mui.com/x/api/date-pickers/date-picker/#slots
- https://mui.com/x/api/date-pickers/pickers-action-bar/#props

Answer (score 5):

`@mui/x-date-pickers` package version `v6.16.0` now has this feature built in:

```
import { DatePicker } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/DatePicker';

<DatePicker
   slotProps={{ field: { clearable: true } }}
/>
```

source: https://github.com/mui/mui-x/releases/tag/v6.16.0

Answer (score 4):

how about this custom component?.

```
const DatePickerClear = (props) => {
  const { onClear } = props;
  return (
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
      <DatePicker
        {...props}
        renderInput={(params) => (
          <div style={{ position: "relative", display: "inline-block" }} >
            <TextField {...params} />
            {props.value &&
              <IconButton style={{ position: "absolute", top: ".5rem", margin: "auto", right: "2rem" }} onClick={() => onClear()}>
                <ClearIcon />
              </IconButton>
            }
          </div>
        )
        }
      /></LocalizationProvider >
  )
}

export default DatePickerClear
```

I give you too a github basic project in react.

[image]

https://github.com/HastaCs/MUI_DatePicker_ClearButton

Comment: This works pretty neat, except when picking a date, the date-selector pop-up flickers in the top-left corner for a second before closing itself. Also, you need to use `slots` prop instead of `renderInput` for newer versions of MUI.

Answer (score 3):

I've tried it many ways but finally what worked for me is to change key while clearing from custom clear button, looks little dirty but that only what I was possibly able to

```
const [pickerKey, setPickerKey] = useState("pickerKey");
const handleClear = useCallback(() => {
    onChange("");
    setPickerKey(Math.random().toString());
}, [onChange]);



<DatePicker
   ...
   key={pickerKey}
   ...
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

MUI DatePicker has a clearable property.  When set to true, it shows a clear button.  You can change the text of the clear button using the clearText property.
I would point out however, that it does not trigger an onChange event, nor is there an onClear event (at the time of writing this post).  So when I am using it, its not possible to change the state that way.  However the onAccept event is fired, and if you pass the value parameter, it will be null.

```
<MobileDatePicker
  open
  clearable
  label="some label"
  inputFormat="yyyy-MM-dd"
  value={stateDate}
  onChange={(date) => updateAvailableDate(date)}
  renderInput={(params) => (
    <TextField
      {...params}
    />
  )}
  onClose={() => hideModal()}
  clearText="Clear me"
  onAccept={(value) => handleSave(value)}
/>
```

See all the api settings here.
https://mui.com/api/date-picker/

Comment: It looks like something changed, I can't find `clearable` option no longer.

Answer (score -2):

This is what I did to make the clear function work. I recently found this solution so I might change this in the future... but for now it's fine.

```
       <MobileDateTimePicker
                ...
                clearable
                clearText="Clear"
                onChange={(newScheduleDateTime) => {
                  if (newScheduleDateTime) {
                    setScheduleDateTime(newScheduleDateTime);
                  } else {
                    setScheduleDateTime(null);
                  }
                }}
              />
```