React + MUI Date picker, controlled as iso string, text input not clearing when string set to empty
Using Mui DatePicker, and controlling the value as a string, if I start typing in the text field and leave it as 01/MM/YYYY, and hit an external clear button that sets the controlled value to null, the text field is not cleared.
This works fine if I,

finish the date, ex: 01/01/2000
control the value as a luxon DateTime object

Working example
For a visual of my issue, the clear button does nothing.

Code below:
import { useState } from "react";
import { DateTime } from "luxon";
import { DatePicker } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/DatePicker";
import { AdapterLuxon } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterLuxon";
import { LocalizationProvider } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/LocalizationProvider";
import { Button } from "@mui/material";

export default function App() {
  const [startOpen, setStartOpen] = useState(false);
  const [val, setVal] = useState(DateTime.now().toISODate());
  return (
    <>
      <div className="App">
        <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterLuxon}>
          <DatePicker
            open={startOpen}
            onClose={() => setStartOpen(false)}
            sx={{ flex: 1 }}
            slotProps={{
              field: {
                clearable: true,
                onClear: () => {},
                onError: () => {},
              },
              textField: {
                onClick: () => setStartOpen(true),
              },
            }}
            onChange={(v) => {
              setVal(v);
            }}
            onError={() => {}}
            value={DateTime.fromISO(val)}
          />
        </LocalizationProvider>
      </div>
      <Button
        onClick={() => {
          setVal(null);
          console.log(val);
        }}
      >
        Clear
      </Button>
    </>
  );
}


Possible duplicate.

You need to set inputRef prop to picker and call below in Clear button callback.
ref.current.value = null;

Here is the full code.
import "./styles.css";
import { useState, useRef } from "react";
import { DateTime } from "luxon";
import { DatePicker } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/DatePicker";
import { AdapterLuxon } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterLuxon";
import { LocalizationProvider } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/LocalizationProvider";
import { Button } from "@mui/material";

export default function App() {
  const [startOpen, setStartOpen] = useState(false);
  const [val, setVal] = useState(DateTime.now().toISODate());
  const ref = useRef();
  return (
    <>
      <div className="App">
        <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterLuxon}>
          <DatePicker
            open={startOpen}
            onClose={() => setStartOpen(false)}
            sx={{ flex: 1 }}
            slotProps={{
              field: {
                clearable: true,
                onClear: () => {},
                onError: () => {},
              },
              textField: {
                onClick: () => setStartOpen(true),
              },
            }}
            onAccept={setVal}
            // onChange={(v) => {
            //   // let dateString: string | null = "";
            //   // if (v) {
            //   //   dateString = v.toISODate();
            //   // }
            //   // onChange(dateString);
            //   debugger;
            //   setVal(v);
            // }}
            onError={() => {}}
            value={DateTime.fromISO(val)}
            inputRef={ref}
          />
        </LocalizationProvider>
      </div>
      <Button
        onClick={() => {
          setVal(() => null);
          ref.current.value = null;
          console.log(val);
        }}
      >
        Clear
      </Button>
    </>
  );
}

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/infallible-gwen-hg5ymh?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A8%2C1

this looks promising, but seems inconsistent if you haven't blurred the field. The value comes back after refocusing as well.

seems below answer is relevant.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/70046051/12519572

      <Button
        onClick={() => {
          setVal(DateTime.now().toISODate());
          console.log(val);
        }}
      >
        Clear
      </Button>


Please give an explanation for your answer.

Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly edit your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
